# Angular JS break ForEach

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have an angular foreach loop and i want to break from loop if i match a value. The following code does not work.

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(count == 1){
    break;
  }
});
```

How can i get this?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just find the value instead of going into a loop. Maybe the example you gave isn't telling the entire story, but I'd rather do what @Aman said below. Why go into the loop as mentioned below and run a check every time when some() does exactly that in a more elegant fashion. Remember that if you treat javascript as a functional language, there should be no point in using these for/while/break type of control structures. That's why foreach, find, some, etc exist

Answer (score 276, accepted):

There's no way to do this. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263. Depending on what you're doing you can use a boolean to just not going into the body of the loop. Something like:

```
var keepGoing = true;
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(keepGoing) {
    if(count == 1){
      keepGoing = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I would rather just add a `!keepGoing && return;` to the top of the function, less code.

Comment: This is not best practices , here angular forEach loop never break , AND there is nothing to break angular.forEach . Native for loop is around 90 % fast than angular.forEach . So it is better to use native for loop when you want to break on condition match . Thanks

Comment: xcatly where I stuck...and this helped..thanks a ton...Anyways I would like to know the reason for making forEach loop unbreakable . If any

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer for it does not break the forEach loop. It is merly a way to not execute all logic inside the loop.

Answer (score 308):

The `angular.forEach` loop can't break on a condition match.

My personal advice is to use a **NATIVE FOR** loop instead of `angular.forEach`.

The NATIVE FOR loop is around **90%** faster then other for loops.

[image: For loop break , for loop test result]

**USE FOR loop IN ANGULAR:**

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] === 1) {
    console.log('Loop is going to break.'); 
    break;
  }
  console.log('Loop will continue.');
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. All it does is finish this particular iteration of the loop. But then it moves on to the next iteration.

Comment: @Ben , Sorry ben , It was my mistake but now i update my answer after long research . I hope this will help you . Thank you

Comment: this test is platform dependent. in my case the Native FOR was 90% slower.

Comment: @LGama :- What is your case ??

Comment: @NishchitDhanani your test was using Chrome31.0.1650.63 on Windows server 2008 R2/ 7 64-bit. Mine was using Chrome 34.0.1847.116 32-bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 64-bit

Comment: http://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-performance test it on your own browser to decide which function you should choose. I have tested on IE11 and it is also as fast as in the screenshot. Also tested Array.some() but it is slower then Array.forEach() on IE11 but could be faster then angular.foreach ;-). Or test it here http://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native (all credits go to the original author, not me ;-))

Comment: which tool is this and how to use this

Comment: That was true in early 2014, but is it still the case ? looks like the issue has been closed : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3221

Comment: Even with jsperf you cannot say "native for is around 90% faster". In your scenario this highly depends on how expensive the execution of the inner function is and how many executions can be saved by exiting the loop (break) early.

Comment: instead of writing for(var i=0 ; i<numbers.length ; i++)'  writing   'for (var i in numbers)'  is a  better way of using for loop in javascript

Answer (score 25):

please use some or every instances of ForEach,

```
Array.prototype.some:
some is much the same as forEach but it break when the callback returns true

Array.prototype.every:
every is almost identical to some except it's expecting false to break the loop.
```

Example for some:

```
var ary = ["JavaScript", "Java", "CoffeeScript", "TypeScript"];

ary.some(function (value, index, _ary) {
    console.log(index + ": " + value);
    return value === "JavaScript";
});
```

Example for every:

```
var ary = ["JavaScript", "Java", "CoffeeScript", "TypeScript"];

ary.every(function(value, index, _ary) {
    console.log(index + ": " + value);
    return value.indexOf("Script") > -1;
});
```

Find more information 
http://www.jsnoob.com/2013/11/26/how-to-break-the-foreach/

Comment: no @AngelS.Moreno, everyone prefer to use a local variable instead of a method designed specifically for the case in hand

Answer (score 19):

Use the Array Some Method

```
 var exists = [0,1,2].some(function(count){
      return count == 1
 });
```

exists will return true, and you can use this as a variable in your function

```
if(exists){
    console.log('this is true!')
}
```

[Array Some Method - Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: For me, the only reason to use `angular.forEach()` is that I have to support IE8, which doesn't have `Array.forEach()`... or `Array.some()`.

Comment: You can polyfill Array.forEach easily.  See bottom of page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, Angular doesn't provide such a function. You may want to use underscore's `find()` function for this (it's basically a forEach which breaks out of the loop once the function returns true).

http://underscorejs.org/#find

Comment: this might solve the problem laterally, but it does not in deed break the loop.

Comment: Or native for loop

Answer (score 6):

If you use jQuery (hence not jqLite) in conjunction with AngularJS you can iterate with $.each - which allows breaking and continuing based on boolean return value expression.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JEcD2/1/

Javascript:

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'yay'];
$.each(array, function(index, element){
    if (element === 'foo') {
        return true; // continue
    }
    console.log(this);
    if (element === 'bar') {
        return false; // break
    }
});
```

**Note:**

Though using jQuery is not bad, both native [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) functions are recommended by MDN as you can read at native [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) documentation:

> "There is no way to stop or break a forEach loop. The solution is to use Array.every or Array.some"

Following examples are provided by MDN:

Array.some:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array){
    return (element >= 10);
}
var passed = [2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBigEnough);
// passed is false
passed = [12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBigEnough);
// passed is true
```

Array.every:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array){
    return (element >= 10);
}
var passed = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
// passed is false
passed = [12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
// passed is true
```

Answer (score 6):

Concretely, you can exit of a `forEach` loop, and of any place, throw an exception.

```
try {
   angular.forEach([1,2,3], function(num) {
      if (num === 2) throw Error();
   });
} catch(e) {
    // anything
}
```

However, it is better if you use other library or implement your own function, a `find` function in this case, so your code is most high-level.

Comment: Well, you did answer the question! I hope no one does that though :)

Comment: Throwing an exception unnecessarily is not good way of handling the situation. Rather check the solution provided by @dnc253 http://stackoverflow.com/a/13844508/698127

Answer (score 5):

Try this as break;

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(count == 1){
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers state, Angular doesn't provide this functionality. jQuery does however, and if you have loaded jQuery as well as Angular, you can use

```
jQuery.each ( array, function ( index, value) {
    if(condition) return false; // this will cause a break in the iteration
})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: The OP asked for an AngularJS solution, the correct answer is NO :)

Answer (score 3):

Normally there is no way to break an "each" loop in javascript. 
What can be done usually is to use "short circuit" method.

```js
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      // if the condition is not met, move on to the next round of iteration.
      if (!condition) return;

      // if the condition is met, do your logic here
      console.log('do stuff.')
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

*`break` isn't possible to achieve in angular forEach, we need to modify forEach to do that.*

```
$scope.myuser = [{name: "Ravi"}, {name: "Bhushan"}, {name: "Thakur"}];  
                angular.forEach($scope.myuser, function(name){
                  if(name == "Bhushan") {
                    alert(name);
                    return forEach.break(); 
                    //break() is a function that returns an immutable object,e.g. an empty string
                  }
                });
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem complete. Please indicate whether `break()` needs to be defined or wether it's already part of angular. Please define if not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var count = 0;
var arr = [0,1,2];
for(var i in arr){
   if(count == 1) break;
   //console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ary = ["JavaScript", "Java", "CoffeeScript", "TypeScript"];
var keepGoing = true;
ary.forEach(function(value, index, _ary) {
    console.log(index)
    keepGoing = true;
    ary.forEach(function(value, index, _ary) {
        if(keepGoing){ 
            if(index==2){
                keepGoing=false;
            }
            else{
                console.log(value)
            }

        }      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.arr = [0, 1, 2];  
$scope.dict = {}
for ( var i=0; i < $scope.arr.length; i++ ) {
    if ( $scope.arr[i] == 1 ) {
        $scope.exists = 'yes, 1 exists';
        break;
    }
 }
 if ( $scope.exists ) {
     angular.forEach ( $scope.arr, function ( value, index ) {
                      $scope.dict[index] = value;
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do this by return. Put the looping part in private function and return when you want to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This example works. Try it.

```
var array = [0,1,2];
for( var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++){
  if(i === 1){
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that he does not want a `for` loop, his use case needs a `foreach` not a `for` probably

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old, but an array filter may do what you need:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2].filter(function (count) {
    return count < 1;
});
```

You can then run `arr.forEach` and other array functions.

I realise that if you intend to cut down on loop operations altogether, this will probably not do what you want. For that you best use `while`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `return` instead of `break`.

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(count == 1){
    return;
  }
});
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: this is not a valid solution. look:

function test() {
angular.forEach([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], function(value, index) {
if(value == 2) return;
console.log(value);
})
}

output: 
> teste();
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Answer (score 0):

Use Return to break the loop.

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(count == 1) {
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelectionChanged(event) {
    let selectdata = event['api']['immutableService']['gridOptionsWrapper']['gridOptions']['rowData'];
    let selected_flag = 0;

    selectdata.forEach(data => {
      if (data.selected == true) {
        selected_flag = 1;
      }
    });

    if (selected_flag == 1) {
      this.showForms = true;
    } else {
      this.showForms = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add $index and do the following:

```
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count, $index) {
     if($index !== 1) {
          // do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to break out of the loop.