# AngularJs ng-checked using a function

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and I am trying to use a function in input `ng-checked="someFunction()"` and I don't know if this is possible or I am doing something wrong. I have function in my controller and I am calling it in view. As far as the function I think it's definitely working and the ng-checked is firing it but returning true or false doesn't change anything. So the question would be is there a way to use function in 'ng-checked' ?

```
$scope.multiAnswers = function (answers, optionId) {
  angular.forEach(answers, function (answer, key) {
    if (answer.option_choice_id == optionId) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Afaik ng-checked is used only with on/off value with a model. So you could exploit the model instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ng-checked` does work with functions. Here is a demo:

```
$scope.getCheckedFalse = function(){
    return false;
};

$scope.getCheckedTrue = function(){
    return true;
};
```

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="getCheckedFalse()"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="getCheckedTrue()"/>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TUdlKMggk3PR4tyHpNBP?p=preview)

Your problem is that you **never** return **true** at the end of the function. `return true;` inside angular.forEach does not help.

Try:

```
$scope.multiAnswers = function (answers, optionId) {
     var returnValue = false;
     angular.forEach(answers, function (answer, key) {
         if (answer.option_choice_id == optionId) {
              returnValue = true;
              return;
         }
     });

     return returnValue;
};
```

It looks like that we cannot break from angular.forEach: [Angular JS break ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach)

To improve performance to break immediately when `answer.option_choice_id == optionId` is **true**. You could try jQuery [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) or using vanilar javascript (for loop).

Comment: that's awesome. .

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is use a state variable as the `ng-checked` expression, eg: `ng-checked="someValue"`. Then it is up to you elsewhere in your code to update that `$scope` value. The problem is that by using a function, it is unaware when in fact it should update its value.

Comment: It's in the scope. Sorry I pass 'this' object later to the scope. It wasn't obvious from the code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I was having similar ideas, the problem is that I can't use the variable because the forms are dynamic. Is there some other way ? Using a filter maybe ?

Comment: You will need to elaborate. Are you able to create a fiddle?

Comment: It's quite hard to make a fiddle. Basically I generate different types forms from database using angularjs. And I want to show which options of check-box were selected in the past by the user.