# Binding multiple checkboxes in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two arrays coming from web service of object. One is all categories and other one is selected categories like this

```
$scope.categories = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "cat1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "cat2" },     
    { "id": 3, "name": "cat3" }, 
    { "id": 4, "name": "cat4" }
];

$scope.selected_category = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "cat1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "cat2" }
];
```

and my markup is like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Category</label>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="item in categories">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.id}}" ng-model="?" ng-checked="?">         
        {{item.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how do I check those checkboxes which are coming as selected. please help!

Thanks

Comment: add `checked` property to `categories`, and then use that to manage checked unchecked objects...

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for your question.

1. You can call a function with ng-checked="checkSelected(item.id)".Pass the id in the function.Then in the controller compare this with the id of the `$scope.selected_category` array and return those id's that match the array
2. You can write a condition directly in ng-checked directive (This is applicable only if your data is not too big).You can find more about this approach here [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701517/angularjs-ng-checked-using-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

I think your $scope.categories should be updated that way :

```
$scope.categories = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "cat1", "isSelected": false },
  { "id": 2, "name": "cat2", "isSelected": false  },     
  { "id": 3, "name": "cat3", "isSelected": false  }, 
  { "id": 4, "name": "cat4", "isSelected": false  }
];
```

And use it that way :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Category</label>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="item in categories">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.id}}" ng-model="item.isSelected">         
    {{item.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

ng-model will take care of selecting or not the checkbox for you

If you really need to have an object with selected categories, you also can do this :

```
$scope.$watch("categories", function(oldVal, newVal){
    //Create your object here
});
```