# calling a function in ng-checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to execute a function on ng-checked in a checkbox.Basically I want to make the checkbox checked  depends upon some condition.I follow
  [AngularJs ng-checked using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701517/angularjs-ng-checked-using-a-function)..It works fine .But I found that the function is calling 6 time !!!

**html code :**

```
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" 
               ng-checked="getCheckedValue()">
        </label>
```

**angular js function  :**

```
            $scope.getCheckedValue = function(){
             alert("checking ...");
             var isChecked=false;
             if(some condition){
              isChecked=true;
               return;
             }
             return isChecked;
            }
```

I got the alert on my js 6 times!!.Please help me out

Comment: A fiddle would be nice. :)

Comment: The digest cycles in angular can run many times ...it's generally better to set a scope variable than use a function in markup. WHy can't you set a variable in your function and use that variable in the markup?

Comment: please check where you called your function getcheckedValue(). Try replacing that inside controller.

Comment: The problem here is you are passing a function as the watch key to angularjs, so any time a digest cycle is executed for the said scope the function will get invoked... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zskxcgsq/1/

Comment: Sir @ArunPJohny I checked your fiddle, on each click function getting executed 3 times now. Please tell me why?

Comment: Thanks all for the responses .As I am new to angular js I have only little ideas about angular js.How can I use a variable inside the function with ng-checked? How can I solve the issue ???

Comment: Hello @user1618820 please check Arun P Johny's fiddle above.

Comment: a simple example could be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zskxcgsq/2/

Comment: @Sudarshan I checked the fiddle ;as you said function is executing 3 times for each button click .I am facing the same problem .Since I am performing some database operation inside the function for checking the value is already present its really affect the performance .So i am searching for an alternative or work around for this

Comment: @ArunPJohny thats a great work and working fine .But in this case the function is invoking on the button click but I dont have a button in my page.Actually I have many columns in my table with checkbox in each column and on loading I want to make some of these checkbox to true

Comment: so you have an array of items where you are using a ng-repeat to display them... is that right

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes absolutely

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="doctor in doctorList">
   <td data-ng-bind="doctor.firstName"></td>
      <td ng-repeat="timeSlot in timeSlots">
      <input type="checkbox"
               ng-            checked="getCheckedFalse(timeSlot,doctor.employeeTypeId)"/>
      </td>
      
     </tr>

Comment: @user1618820 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zskxcgsq/3/

Comment: can you share sample data of `doctorList`

Comment: doctor list [{"id":2,"firstName":"vivek","lastName":"vk","presentAddressId":0,"permanentAddressId":0,"alternateAddressId":0,"pincode":null,"state":null,"country":null,"age":null,"gender":"m","birthDate":null,"phoneNumber":null,"employeeTypeId":2,"designation":null,"specializationId":0,"departmentId":0,"dateOfJoining":null,"shift":null,"imagePath":null,"educationDetail":null,"experianceDetail":null}]

Comment: now I got some idea my date list is ["2015-05-05","2015-05-06"] .So I can do a watch on my timeSlots list but the problem here is I want to pass time slot and doctor id to my function

Comment: you can do it without an watch - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zskxcgsq/4/

Comment: @ArunPJohny a big thanks for your effort .It really helps me :)

Comment: if that solved the problem I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I think you can update the checked state without using a watch after the doctors list is loaded

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="doctor in doctorList">
        <td data-ng-bind="doctor.firstName"></td>
        <td ng-repeat="timeSlot in timeSlots">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="doctor[timeSlot]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then once the doctor list is loaded

```
    angular.forEach($scope.doctorList, function (doctor) {
            angular.forEach($scope.timeSlots, function (slot) {
            doctor[slot] = $scope.isChecked(doctor, slot)
            });
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zskxcgsq/)