# Simple async code with angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs

flag is always false. how can I do?

code here:

```
var list = ['NOVALUE','VALUE','NOVALUE'];
var flag = false;
angular.forEach(list, function(value){
    if('VALUE' === value){
        flag = true;
    }
});
console.log(flag);
```

---

sorry, i missed something

Comment: what are you trying to do..?

Comment: because last element making it `false` again `'VALUE' === 'NOVALUE'`

Comment: if you're trying to check if an array has a value, you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: You'd need to `break` out of that loop when you found a match. Unfortunately there's no breaking mechanism in `angular.forEach`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `.indexOf()`, as Alexander demonstrates:

```
var list = ['NOVALUE','VALUE','NOVALUE'];

var flag = list.indexOf('VALUE') !== -1;

console.log(flag);
```

or `.some()` in the more general case:

```
var list = ['NOVALUE','VALUE','NOVALUE'];

var flag = list.some(function (value) {
    return value === 'VALUE';
});

console.log(flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the last value in list is "NOVALUE" so it is always false.
You can do

```
flag = list.indexOf('VALUE') > -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break; so that whentrue statement comes it will go out of the loop

```
var list = ['NOVALUE','VALUE','NOVALUE'];
        var flag = false;
        for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        if('VALUE' === value)
         {
          flag=true;                
          break;
          }else
          flag=false;
        }
        console.log(flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ['NOVALUE','VALUE','NOVALUE'];
var flag = false;
angular.forEach(list, function(value){
    if (value === 'VALUE'){
        flag = true;
    }
    else{
        flag = false;
    }
    console.log(flag);
});

//false, true, false
```

Comment: Answers are better if you provide an explanation of why\how they work