# angularjs break forEach in $http success

Tags: angularjs, promise, ionic-framework

I have following code in Ionic framework,

```
var stopScan = false;
$scope.StopScan = function() {
 stopScan = true;
};

$scope.ScanContacts = function() {

 Contacts.unchecked().then(function(contacts) {

  var promise = $q.all(null);
  angular.forEach(contacts, function(contact) {

    promise = promise.then(function() {

     return $http.post(apiEndpoint+'/check', {number: contact.number})
      .success(function(res) {

        Contacts.update(contact.id, res);
        if(stopScan)
         // do break loop;
       })

       .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
       });
     });
   });
  });
 };
```

It's do sending http request in loop synchronously, and break on $http error, exactly like I wanted. But how I do break the loop in the $http success? I've tried `throw 'Scan stopped';` and `$q.reject('Scan stopped');` but no success.

Comment: I am not really clear what are you trying to achieve as a whole. But I think it's better if you wrap the asynchronous http post call into promise and call resolve or reject accordingly. Regarding breaking the loop, I don't see any loop in your code. But you can always do if-else statement to check the stopScan value. If it is true, just call the break which will break the loop in JS

Comment: In your example, `stopScan` is already `true` - so, why even do the loop? But in general, where is `stopScan` supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run with parallel HTTP requests, then go with @NewDev's answer.

However if you want to stick with serial requests, then "breaking out of the loop" couldn't be simpler.

All you need to do is throw, which won't break as such but will send the constructed promise chain down its error path. At the stop point, there will be no unreturned requests and no more requests will be sent.

I would write something like this, using `contacts.reduce(...)` to build the chain.

```
$scope.ScanContacts = function() {
    return Contacts.unchecked().then(function(contacts) {
        return contacts.reduce(function (p, contact) {
            return p.then(function() {
                return $http.post(apiEndpoint + '/check', { number: contact.number })
                .then(function(res) {
                    if(stopScan) throw new Error('scan stopped');
                    Contacts.update(contact.id, res);//you can choose to service the last response or not but placing this line above or below the throw line.
                }, function(err) {
                    // As the second .then param, this callback will catch any http errors but not the 'scan stopped' error.
                    // By catching http errors, the scan will be allows to continue.
                    // To stop on http error, either remove this callback or rethrow the error.
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        }, $q.when());
    });
};
```

**[Here's evidence](http://jsfiddle.net/skqugfvc/)** that throwing will give the required "stop" effect.

If throwing doesn't work in the real code, then it would seem that something else is wrong.

Comment: The only problem with this is that you are throwing an error on what really should be successful (I believe; I'm not sure if `stopScan` is supposed to be an error). Yes, you can catch it right away, but something is just off about that semantically.

Comment: @trysis, throwing within a promise chain for the purpose of flow control is totally legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all, `angular.forEach` does not support breaking (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263))

**Second**, `break` statement must be directly nested within the loop, even if it was a `for` or `while` loop.

**And lastly**, `.success` is happening asynchronously, ***after*** the loop has executed, so breaking there via some other mean would have been meaningless anyway.

It seems like you expect `stopScan` to be set asynchronously elsewhere (for example, in response to a click from the user), but you have to decide exactly what it means to stop - does it mean "do not make any more `$http.post` requests", or does it mean "make all the requests, but don't not process the response?". (Your example seems to imply the latter, because you're attempting to handle it in `.success`, but you should know, though, that `POST` typically implies that changes were made on the server).

You have to understand that once you kick off an HTTP request, it's going out (or it's pending, subject to max number of connections, which is browser-dependent).

So, what you could do is fire all of the requests at once and in parallel, and then manually "timeout" (`$http` supports a promise-based `timeout`) the ones that haven't been completed:

```
var stopScanTimeout = $q(function(resolve){
  $scope.stopScan = function(){
    resolve();
  }
})

var promises = [];
angular.forEach(contacts, function(contact) {
  var httpPromise = $http({ method:  "POST",
                            url:     apiEndpoint+'/check', 
                            data:    {number: contact.number},
                            timeout: stopScanTimeout })
                         .then(function(response){ return response.data; },
                               function(error)   { return {error: error};});
  promises.push(httpPromise);
});
```

Then you could handle all the results together, and some would be "errors" (but "soft" errors) if they were not completed in time:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(results){
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length, i++){
    var result = results[i];

    if (result.error) continue;

    // otherwise, process the result
    Contacts.update(contact.id, result);
  }
})
```