# Exit of foreach when pass by a if conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a logic problem in my code.

```
object.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.a === $scope.a) {
    //doSomething
  }
  else {
    //doOtherStuff
 }
});
```

So, basically, I want to run the object and compare if the $scope exist inside the object. If the $scope exist, do something and exit on the forEach, else, do other thing and also exit. How is the best way to do that?

My logic problem is that it's running inside the forEach and for every index, is doing something. Maybe I have to use another approach that I don't know yet, could you help me?

Comment: This answer may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach

Comment: I hope what you declared with the name `object` is in fact an array.

Comment: It is a bit strange that you want to exit in both cases (condition true of false), which practically means you will never really iterate, but only want to act on the first item only. Then the question is: why do you use `forEach`, and don't just pick the first element and do your logic on it?

Comment: @trincot is not just for the first element, I want to iterate inside the object to compare if $scope.a existing inside the item, if exist, I want to do something and exit.

Comment: Ok,  it is just that in your question you wrote *else, do other thing **and also exit***. That would mean you always exit.... I suppose that was not what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
Object.keys(object).every(function(item) {
    if (some_exit_condition) {
        return false; // don't call this callback again for next items
    else {
        // don't stop, keep going
        return true;
    }
});
```

If `object` is an array-like object (iterable), you don't need to call `Object.keys()` on it. It depends what you want to iterate. With `Object.keys()`, you iterate the owned properties of that object, and inside the callback function you would write `object[item]` to get the value of that property.

The method [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) has similar behaviour, but there you must return `true` to stop the iterations, and `false` to continue.

Both `every()` and `some()` have a boolean return value, which also distinguishes them from `forEach()`. With that return value you can know if there was an explicit "exit" or not.

Comment: Yeah, `every` works for a specific behaviour of algorithm, this problem was half solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simplify your code using array.prototype.filter().

You can see more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

You have compatibility with ie9, but I think there should be a jquery function that can do the same.