# How can I completely exit from inside a .forEach that is inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this method:

```
    wordFormDirty = (): boolean => {
    var self = this;
    angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
        var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormId
        if (!self[wordFormNgForm].$pristine) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

From what I see this never returns true. Can someone give me advice as to how I can implement this so that a form that's not pristine will make the wordFormDirty() method return true.

Comment: The inner function returns true, I guess you want the outer function to return true? Just use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: try using `some` and see.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach

Comment: BTW this is TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you  try this, in this case, if I've undestand  the issue, the first time there is a value true the result is set to true otherwise it remains false

```
wordFormDirty = (): boolean => {
    var self = this;
    var result = false;
    angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
        var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormId
        if (!self[wordFormNgForm].$pristine) {
            result = true;
        }

    });
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to get a result directly from walking the `Array`, consider using other methods than `forEach`. E.g.:

```
return Object.values(this.word.wordForms).some(
  ({ wordFormId }) => !this[`wordFormNgForm_${wordFormId}`].$pristine
);
```

Comment: I like this idea very much but can you explain what is meant by Object.values in your example and how it would be used in my method?

Comment: I wrote my code sample in ES7. If you environment doesn't support some of the features, you can polyfill them or find alternatives, e.g. use [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some) from Lodash. Or if `wordForms` is already an `Array`, you can use `.some` directly.