# Return from angular.foreach is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function like this that works, but I process the whole array before it returns:

```
function getDefault(name, preferences){
    console.log("Getting " + name);
    var v;
    angular.forEach(preferences, function(value, key){
    console.log("Checking " + value.name);
    if(value.name == name){
        v = value.value;
        console.log("Got match, value = " + v);
    }
    });
    console.log("v is " + v);
    return v;
}
```

When I do this (return from within the `forEach` block, I get undefined, but it says that the correct value is returned.

```
function getDefault(name, preferences){
    console.log("Getting " + name);
    var v;
    angular.forEach(preferences, function(value, key){
    console.log("Checking " + value.name);
    if(value.name == name){
        v = value.value;
        console.log("Got match, value = " + v);
        console.log("v is " + v);
        return v;  // The function returns but the value is undefined
    }
    });
}
```

s
What's the deal here?  Is angular somehow creating a strange scope that goes away?

Comment: I guess, you cannot return from `forEach` like `forEach` in JS & lodash/underscore except `return false;` which will break out of the loop.

Comment: You need [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Maybe this one can clarify more and help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preferences.every(function(preference, index) {

```
if (preference.value===name){
    v = preference.value;
    return false;
}
else return true;
```

});

return v

Answer (score 2):

In your second example `getDefault` returns `undefined` because that is the default behavour in JavaScript when you don't have a `return` statement.

This would be more obvious if you separate out your nested function into a named function:

```
function innerFunction(value, key){
    console.log("Checking " + value.name);
    if(value.name == name){
        v = value.value;
        console.log("Got match, value = " + v);
        console.log("v is " + v);
        return v;  // The function returns but the value is undefined
    }
}

function getDefault(name, preferences){
    console.log("Getting " + name);
    var v;
    angular.forEach(preferences, innerFunction);
    //getDefault does not return anything
}
```

Incidentally both versions of your code will process the whole array.  To avoid that you will need to use a different sort of foreach; perhaps just the native JavaScript one.

Comment: I don't understand this

Comment: ok, fair enough.  I have added the innerFunction now.  Do you see how my code is same as yours?  You have two functions and I have two functions.  Do you see the the function called getDefault does not have a return statement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that his is happening because you are returning a value inside the forEach context, so it's returning something but the foreach is ignoring it because it does not returns anything (i.e. `var return = angular.forEach...` does not make sense with `forEach`). Consequently, the function is returning undefined (you don't have a return of the function).

Seems that you can't break the `forEach` loop so instead of using it you can use the normal `for` and break it when you find the value that you want.

```
for (key in preferences) {
    if(preferences[key].name == name){
        v = preferences[key].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer?  You just re-stated the problem.

Comment: I was trying to explain you the problem and the difference between putting the return inside or outside the `forEach`

Comment: Right, and I demonstrated that by posting the 2 versions of the function

Comment: I think I missunderstood what you want. Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach seems that you can't break the `forEach` so you have to iterate over the whole array.

Comment: I have added a possible alternative to avoid the problem.