# Angularjs foreach loop not return false

Tags: php, angularjs

i am using angularjs foreach loop following,

```
$scope.Qsets=infoData;
          try {
           angular.forEach($scope.Qsets,function(value,index){
               if( typeof value === 'undefined' ) {
                   return false;
                };
            });
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
//if not false other code here
```

when my `if( typeof value === 'undefined' )` is become true then it should break loop by returning false. but its not breaking loop, its continue with below codes. how can i prevent executing other code if my `if( typeof value === 'undefined' )` become true?

Comment: did you got any error in console?

Comment: try to use variable and hold `true/false` and then outside of `foreach` return that like: `return isTrue`.

Comment: @Manikandan its enter the 'if' statement block but not break the loop

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @Manikandan not working

Comment: Show your full code. Add plunkr.

Comment: Returning `false` inside of Angular's `forEach` **will not** break the loop. [See me](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263)

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach (use native for loops, angular's forEach will not break out).

Answer (score 0):

Returning false inside of Angular's forEach will not break the loop. use for loop or something like this.

```
var keepGoing = true;
angular.forEach([0,1,2], function(count){
  if(keepGoing) {
    if(count == 1){
      keepGoing = false;
    }
  }
});
```