# Angular ForEach in Angular4/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach

I see many answers about using ngFor when I search for this, but I understand ngFor.  I'm asking about the `angular.forEach()` constructor used in my Angular 1 controllers.  These are flagged as errors in TS and do not compile.

For example, I have one with a nested loop:

```
 _this.selectChildren = function (data, $event) {
  var parentChecked = data.checked;
  angular.forEach(_this.hierarchicalData, function (value, key) {
    angular.forEach(value.children, function (value, key) {
      value.checked = parentChecked;
    });
  });
};
```

What does this construct look like in Typescript for Angular 4?

Comment: `_this.hierarchicalData.forEach` should work.. why you need angular.forEach here. native is best :p

Comment: try [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

in angular4 foreach like that. try this.

```
 selectChildren(data, $event) {
      let parentChecked = data.checked;
       this.hierarchicalData.forEach(obj => {
          obj.forEach(childObj=> {
            value.checked = parentChecked;
         });
      });
    }
```

Comment: You can choose after set seeing this article.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach

Comment: `forEach`, uppercase `E`. :-)

Answer (score 15):

you can try typescript's `For`  :

```
selectChildren(data , $event){
   let parentChecked : boolean = data.checked;
   for(let o of this.hierarchicalData){
      for(let child of o){
         child.checked = parentChecked;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `for` is not TypeScript. It's JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

```
arrayData.forEach((key : any, val: any) => {
                        key['index'] = val + 1;

                        arrayData2.forEach((keys : any, vals :any) => {
                            if (key.group_id == keys.id) {
                                key.group_name = keys.group_name;
                            }
                        })
                    })
```

Answer (score -1):

In Typescript use the For Each like below.

```
selectChildren(data, $event) {
let parentChecked = data.checked;
for(var obj in this.hierarchicalData)
    {
        for (var childObj in obj )
        {
            value.checked = parentChecked;
        }
    }
}
```