# how to use for each in angular4

Tags: angular

i have a doubt, i have 2 arrays

```
A=[2,2,3];
```

[image]

i create both array by pushing values .but when i use second array with foreach i didn't get values to display.

```
b.foreach((test,index)=>{
   console.log(test+"_0");
  }
)
```

i am using this format for extract values. 
is it is wrong ? need to change anything?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You aren't showing your full inputs or your full outputs.

Comment: This link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502267/angular-foreach-in-angular4-typescript

Comment: 1) It's `forEach()`, case sensitive ~foreach~ doesn't work 2) You should use `for (let item in array) { ... }` syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in or a standard for loop in general.

Answer (score 0):

With angular and Typescript you need to use as,

```
for (let item of this.data) { 
    console.log(item +"_0");
}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkzbbh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: check the updated answer and demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkzbbh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: this one i know , but my code structure is like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehdgya   , because the values in  data1 and data2 are  get from some rest call, so the  format is just the same in my code

Comment: but still i am not understand the difference

Comment: ,because usually the error comes when i use push statement

Comment: difference is you are using in and in the sample it is of

Answer (score 0):

**forEach** is always be in camelCase,

See this,

```
b.forEach((test,index) =>{
   console.log(test+"_"+index);
});
```