# how to return or exit from the $scope function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In certain condition, I want to exit from my $scope function.I am trying this using **return**. But no luck it returns only from each loop, not from the main scope function. In my code, even d.xyz is true f2 function is getting called. I want to exit from f1 if xyz of d gets true.

```
$scope.f1 = function(){
 angular.foreach(data, function(d){
  if(d.xyz){
   return; // tried with return false also
  }
  if(d.abc){
  //some code 
  }
  $scope.f2();
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.f1 = function(x = true){
 angular.foreach(data, function(d){
  if(d.xyz){
   x = false;
   return; // tried with return false also
  }
  if(d.abc){
  //some code 
  }
  $scope.f2();
 })
 if (!x){
  return;
 }
}
```

Basically you are not exiting `f1()`. This will do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really exit from angular's forEach function. The best you can do, is make sure the callback is returned every iteration after your exit condition is true.

So you would do it like this:

```
$scope.f1 = function(){
    var stopRunning = false;
    angular.foreach(data, function(d){
        if(stopRunning){
            return;
        }
        if(d.xyz){
            stopRunning = true;
            return;
        }
        if(d.abc){
            //some code 
        }
        $scope.f2();
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to exit from the f1 function if the condition is true. Now its exit from for loop only.

Comment: Well, if you're not doing anything else in the f1 function, then effectively it exits from the function when the loop finishes. So with the above you get exactly what you're asking. You can't directly exit the outer function from within an inner callback function. That's just not possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Dam, I did in that way solved the issue. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

```js
     angular.module("test",[]).controller("testC",function($scope){
         $scope.data = [{"test":1},{"test":2}];
         $scope.IsExist=false;
         $scope.testF=function() {
         for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
              if($scope.data[i].test==1){ 
              alert(1);
               $scope.IsExist=true;
              }else if($scope.data[i].test){
              }
              
              if($scope.IsExist)
              {
               return false;
              }
              $scope.testF();
             }
          }
         $scope.testF();
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testC">   
        </div>
```

Comment: No luck with return false, still f2() getting called

Answer (score 0):

You should use return statement in your function. It is not exiting as you are using return in angular.foreach callback function. Try using outside.

Answer (score -2):

I think You should use `break;`. if You are using `return;` this works like a `continue;`

Comment: Oh, it's foreach. Sorry.
Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843972/angular-js-break-foreach

Native For is the best way.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*